# Howler.js sprites cease to work after app switching

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, html5-audio, howler.js

I'm using **howler.js** to play sounds on my PWA. If I don't use `html5: true` when initialising a sound sprite, the sounds cease to play if I switch apps and come back to the PWA (iPadOS 15.4.1). They work just fine in the browser but not if I install the PWA.

If I do set `html5: true` when initialising the sprite, the sounds do keep playing after witching apps. The problem is that when I do that and try to play multiple sound sprites on top of each other, howler.js plays the full sound file and not just the designated part of the sprite.

I can fix everything by getting rid of the sprite and adding all the sounds as separate files. I'd prefer to have them in the sprite to reduce the number of files and downloads.

Comment: Exact same thing happens on iPhone/iOS.

Comment: I just changed to individual files to circumvent the bug.